# Send data to ES using Python script , in memory modification to json

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, devops

I have a python code which pulls data from the SQS queue & then created a download.json file which gets indexed to the ES server using a small .sh script.

The Python code for pulling SQS data is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import os
import json
import uuid
import time
import boto.sqs
import boto
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read('/home/ubuntu/config.ini')

#get details via config file

region = parser.get('default', 'aws_region')
access_key = parser.get('default', 'aws_access_key')
secret_key = parser.get('default', 'aws_secret_key')
queue_name = parser.get('default', 'sqs_queue_name')

sqs = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(region,aws_access_key_id=access_key,aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
q = sqs.get_queue(queue_name) #SQS queue name

#text_file = open('download.json', 'w')
m = q.read(visibility_timeout=15)
if m == None:
  print "No message!"
else:
  with open('/home/ubuntu/download.json', 'w') as json_data:
    print m.get_body()
    json_data.write(m.get_body())   

    json_data.close()
    q.delete_message(m)
    print "Push To ES"
    os.system('/home/ubuntu/./push_to_ES.sh')
    print "Cleaning the temporary json file"
    os.remove('/home/ubuntu/download.json')
    print "++++++ SUCCESSFUL RUN +++++++"
```

The /push_to_ES.sh script looks like :

```
echo "Pushing json file to index"
epoch=`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S`
curl -XPOST -i localhost:9200/i-a524df7c-$epoch/ -d '{
"settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 1
},
"mappings" : {
    "_default_":{
        "_timestamp" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "store" : true
        }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPOST -i localhost:9200/i-a524df7c-$epoch/server?fields=_timestamp -d  @/home/ubuntu/download.json
```

I need to get rid of the script and do this by one single python script , i.e send data to ES using the Python script without saving content to the 'download.json'

download.json:

```
{
    "facter": {
        "blockdevice_xvda_size": 42949672960,
        "blockdevices": "xvda,xvdb",
        "fqdn": null,
        "hardwaremodel": "x86_64",
        "hostname": "qatest",
        "instanceid": "i-4a87",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.00.11",
        "is_virtual": "true",
        "kernelrelease": "3.13.0-48-generic",
        "lsbdistcodename": "trusty",
        "lsbdistdescription": "Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS",
        "macaddress": "02:9d:c2:c3:200:df",
        "memoryfree": "2.74 GB",
        "memorytotal": "3.68 GB",
        "netmask": "255.255.255.234",
        "operatingsystem": "Ubuntu",
        "operatingsystemrelease": "14.04",
        "processor0": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz",
        "processorcount": "1",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "uniqueid": "007f0100",
        "uptime": "5 days"
    },
    "webapps": {
        "kill_switch": {
            "version": "4.0.671"
        }
    }
}
```

What can be done ??

Comment: You should give a try to the [Python bulk helpers](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers)

Comment: wow .. this looks quite cool.. though i am little foggy on how to get this in my code.. because i simple want my sqs json data to be sent to the ES..

Comment: Can you show how your JSON data looks like?

Comment: uploaded/changed my question